# How do I show a map from a Mapbox Project with the Mapbox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, mapbox

I've created a Project (Map?) at https://www.mapbox.com/editor, which has given me a "Map ID". After a bunch of googling and searching, I finally worked out that (I think?) you're supposed to embed this Map ID within a URL and pass it in to the `-[MGLMapView initWithFrame:styleURL:]` initializer method. I've tried the following:

```
NSURL *styleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mapbox://my_username.abcdef123455"];
self.mapView = [[MGLMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds styleURL:styleURL];
```

But I get the following in the debugging console:

> [ERROR] {Map}[Setup]: loading style failed: HTTP status code 401

Am I setting it up wrong? Do I need to enable permissions or something in the Mapbox admin UI?

### Update 1

I just discovered that the online docs at https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/Classes/MGLMapView.html say that the URL should be in the form `mapbox://styles/<user>/<style>`. When I try that, I got the following crash on thread "Map":

> malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=685248512) failed (error code=3)
>
>   *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc

This is the relevant part of the stack trace:

```
#8  0x32ea286a in operator new(unsigned long) ()
#9  0x32ea6546 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long) ()
#10 0x32ea658e in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#11 0x00265390 in mbgl::util::mapbox::normalizeStyleURL(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#12 0x0022242e in mbgl::DefaultFileSource::request(mbgl::Resource const&, uv_loop_s*, std::__1::function<void (mbgl::Response const&)>) ()
#13 0x001ecf34 in mbgl::MapContext::setStyleURL(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#14 0x001ea85a in mbgl::util::RunLoop::Invoker<auto mbgl::util::Thread<mbgl::MapContext>::bind<void (mbgl::MapContext::*)(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)>(void (mbgl::MapContext::*)(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&))::'lambda'(void (mbgl::MapContext::*&&)(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)), std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::operator()() ()
#15 0x00268662 in mbgl::util::RunLoop::process() ()
#16 0x002ad15a in uv__async_event at /Users/kkaefer/Code/mason/libuv-0.10.28/mason_packages/.build/libuv-0.10.28/src/unix/async.c:80
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue here is that raster maps created with [the editor](https://www.mapbox.com/editor) are not compatible with [GL styles](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/). The [new Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) (that's currently in private beta) is our tool for creating GL-compatible maps.

Loading a GL style with Mapbox iOS SDK is done like so:

```
NSURL *styleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8"];    
self.mapView = [[MGLMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds styleURL:styleURL];
```

Where `mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8` is a default style that follows the `mapbox://styles/user/styleHash` pattern.

(In any case, a malformed style URL should not crash and [we'll make that more robust](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2695).)

Comment: To load a raster map, wrap it first in a GL style: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/raster-styles/

Comment: Do you have to upload a file to your own server in order to view a Mapbox Editor map in the Mapbox iOS SDK, you can't just embed the JSON in your app bundle?

Comment: That is correct, local style loading is currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Access Token and use `info.plist`. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The order somehow matters. Make sure put this parameters in info.plist "MGLMapboxAccessToken" with new generated token and rebuild the project. It should work